# How to display values of a column inside bars of a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Using the code below, I could create the below graph. I would like to make some customization as follows:

1- drop the numbers from the beginning of labels in the legend (e.g.,4.Male NCG to Male NCG) but do not change the order of values

2- display the values of meanHLE_ inside the bars and define using a new legend

3-separate male and female categories in the graph

[image: What I have]

**#my data**

```
sample_label<-c("4.Male NCG","4.Male NCG","4.Male NCG",
                    "5.Male caregivers<14h/w","5.Male caregivers<14h/w",
                    "5.Male caregivers<14h/w","6.Male caregivers>=14h/w",
                    "6.Male caregivers>=14h/w","6.Male caregivers>=14h/w",
                    "7.Female NCG","7.Female NCG","7.Female NCG", 
                    "8.Female caregivers<14h/w", "8.Female caregivers<14h/w",
                    "8.Female caregivers<14h/w", "9.Female caregivers>=14h/w",
                    "9.Female caregivers>=14h/w","9.Female caregivers>=14h/w")

        Age_Group_<-c("50-51","60-61","70-71","50-51","60-61","70-71",
                      "50-51","60-61","70-71","50-51","60-61","70-71",
                      "50-51","60-61","70-71","50-51","60-61","70-71")
        meanTLE_<-c(32.4,24,16.3,34.4,25.6,17.3,33.4,24.7,16.8,
                    36,26.8,18.1,37.3,27.9,18.8,36.6,27.3,18.5)
        meanHLE_<-c(24.8,18.3,12.3,27.2,20.2,13.6,25.3,18.7,12.6,
                    28.8,21.4,14.4,30.7,22.9,15.4,29.1,21.6,14.5)
```

## 2.plot section

```
gender<-data.frame(sample_label,Age_Group_,meanTLE_,meanHLE_)
ggplot(gender, aes(x =Age_Group_, y = meanTLE_, fill=sample_label)) + geom_bar(stat ="identity", position = "dodge2") + #fill = "#B61E2E"
  geom_text(
    aes(label = meanTLE_),
    vjust = 0,
    colour = "black", 
    position = position_dodge(width=0.9),
    fontface = "bold",
    size=3,
    angle = 90,
    hjust = 0
  ) +ylim(0,50)+

  labs(
    x = "Age Groups",
    y = "Total Life Expactacny",
    face = "bold"
  ) +
  # coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  # scale_fill_manual(values=c("meanHLE_")) + 
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),legend.text = element_text(face = "bold"),plot.title = element_text(
    hjust = 0.5,
    size = 15,
    colour = "Black",
    face = "bold"
  ),
  plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, color = "black", face = "bold", size=12.5))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the plot below does most of what you indicated in your OP and comments. However, I think this plot is very busy and the patterns aren't as transparent as they could be, so I've added a couple of other options.

```
library(tidyverse)

pd = position_dodge(0.9)

gender %>% 
  mutate(sex=str_extract(sample_label, "Male|Female"),
         sample_label=gsub(".*ale ", "", sample_label),
         sample_label=fct_relevel(sample_label, "NCG")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x =Age_Group_, y = meanTLE_, fill=sample_label, group=sample_label)) + 
  # Dodge value labels and bars by same amount
  geom_col(position = pd, width=0.85) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", meanTLE_)), hjust=0,
            colour = "black", fontface = "bold", size=3, angle = 90,
            # Dodge value labels and bars by same amount
            position = pd) + 
  geom_col(aes(y=meanHLE_), width=0.4, size=0.2, colour="grey50", fill="white", position=pd) +
  geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", meanHLE_), 
                y=meanHLE_, colour=sample_label), position=pd,
            colour = "black", fontface = "bold", size=3, angle = 90,) +
  geom_text(data=. %>% 
              group_by(sex) %>%
              filter(Age_Group_=="70-71", grepl(">=14", sample_label)) %>% 
              ungroup %>% 
              pivot_longer(starts_with("mean")), hjust=0, colour="grey30", size=3,
            aes(x=3.5, y=value, label=gsub("mean(.*)_", "\\1", name))) +
  facet_grid(cols=vars(sex)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,41), expand=c(0,0)) +
  expand_limits(x=3.9) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=hcl(seq(15,375,length=4)[1:3], 100, 80)) +
  labs(x = "Age Groups", y = "Total Life Expectancy") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 15, colour = "Black", face = "bold"),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, color = "black", face = "bold", size=12.5))
```

[image]

The plot below gets rid of the bars and uses values as point markers. I've reshaped the data to long format so that we need only a single call to each geom to plot the values and we can generate a legend with a color mapping. I've added subtle lines just to guide the eye. If you want to remove them, set `size=0` in `geom_line`. Don't get rid of the `geom_line` call, as it's necessary in order to generate the legend.

```
gender %>% 
  mutate(sex=str_extract(sample_label, "Male|Female"),
         sample_label=gsub(".*ale ", "", sample_label)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("mean")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=sample_label, x=value, colour=name, group=name)) + 
    geom_line(size=0.4, alpha=0.5) +
    geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", value)), 
              fontface = "bold", size=3, show.legend=FALSE) + 
    facet_grid(rows=vars(sex, Age_Group_)) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,40), expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_colour_discrete(labels=c("Healthy", "Total")) +
    labs(x = "Mean (years)",
         title="Life expectancy by age, sex, and caregiver status") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
          axis.title.y=element_blank(),
          legend.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 15, face = "bold"),
          plot.caption = element_text(hjust=0, color="black", face="bold", size=12.5),
          strip.text.y=element_text(angle=0),
          legend.position="bottom",
          legend.box.margin=margin(t=-10)) +
    guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=3, alpha=1)))
```

[image]

This version seems to me to be the most transparent regarding the key patterns in the data. The data value text labels overlap, so maybe dodging or using point markers would be more effective.

```
gender %>% 
  mutate(sex=str_extract(sample_label, "Male|Female"),
         sample_label=gsub(".*ale ", "", sample_label)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("mean")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=value, x=Age_Group_, colour=sample_label)) + 
    geom_line(aes(linetype=name, group=interaction(name, sample_label)), 
              size=0.6, alpha=0.3) +
    geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", value)), size=3, show.legend=FALSE) + 
    facet_grid(cols=vars(sex)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,40), expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_linetype_discrete(labels=c("Healthy", "Total")) +
    labs(x = "Age Group", y="years", 
         colour="Caregiver Status", linetype="Life Expectancy Type",
         title="Life expectancy by age, sex, and caregiver status") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 15, face = "bold"),
          plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, color = "black", face = "bold", size=12.5)) +
    guides(linetype=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE, override.aes=list(size=1)),
           colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=1, alpha=1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Haha, I was editing my answer after seeing that several points was not addressed. Too late. Too bad for me ;)

Comment: This is great thanks. Please let me clear up my question. I would like to keep the labels as they shown in my graph and display the meanHLE- values (another variable) inside the bars. I would like to use another bar inside the current bars to do so.

Comment: Also, I was wondering if I can drop male and female words from the legend and use same color for both charts. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for the great graphs. The bar graph makes perfect sense in this context. Is there any way to keep the original order of labels in the legend and in the graph so that it reads as NCG, caregivers<14h/w, and caregivers>=14h/w. I am asking this because the entire study organized three groups in this way. Also, I was wondering if I could use a single color (for example white) for the HLE bars and label it as HLE="the number". Thank you again for your assistance.

Comment: Great! This is exactly, what I was looking for. One last thing. How can I rename NCG to Non-caregivers?

Comment: You can recode it before feeding the data to ggplot, or you can use the labels argument to scale_fill_discrete to recode it during plotting.